Why is this command not working in Windows PowerShell?
I am attempting to connect between Windows PowerShell and MySQL.
Why am I receiving this error from the Windows PowerShell?
mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb;" -u root -p
mysql : The term 'mysql' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb;" -u root -p
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mysql:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I tried copy-pasting the command mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb;" -u root -p into the Windows PowerShell.
I expected for a database to appear in MySQL.
I only received an error.

Error message seems pretty self-explanatory, PowerShell cannot find a command named mysql. Try setting Set-Alias mysql C:\actual\path\to\mysql.exe before running mysql, or ensure the directory containing mysql.exe is present in the PATH env variable

It is unlikely you can CREATE DB; prior to login.

How do I ensure the directory containing mysql.exe is present in the PATH env variable?
